# container encountered an error during hcsshim::System::Start: failure in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container exited unexpectedly

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a Windows container image from an `ASP.NET MVC` application and facing the following error:

```bash
container <hash> encountered an error during hcsshim::System::Start: failure in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container exited unexpectedly. (0xc0370106)
```

- The version of Docker: `20.10.17`, build `100c701`
- The version of Docker Desktop: `4.11.1`

I've tried using both a WSL2 backend and the legacy Hyper-V backend.

The error remains the same.

I started seeing this issue yesterday and haven't had luck trying to fix it.

Comment: Please add your Dockerfile/docker-compose files

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1.26-nanoserver-1809
WORKDIR /app
COPY bin/x64/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish .

# Copy the shim files into the container.
COPY bin/x64/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Monitoring/DockerShim Geneva

# Configure the shim to run on container start. Install must be run as an admin.
USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN ["Geneva/MonAgentDockerShimLauncher.exe", "-install"]

CMD ["dotnet", "UserRPService.dll"]

This is the Dockerfile that's having issues.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the exact similar situation, I managed to get it working again by removing everything 'docker related' from the solution, and added it back again by right-clicking the `MVC-project` and `[Add]->[Docker Support..]` back in there.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error message when trying to mount a directory as `D:\` on a windows docker container:

```
docker run --rm --volume ${PWD}:"D:\" -it my-image
docker: Error response from daemon: container encountered an error during hcs::System::Start: failure in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container exited unexpectedly. (0xc0370106).
```

The problem was resolved by mounting as a subdirectory of `C:\` instead:

```
docker run --rm --volume ${PWD}:"C:\HOST" -it my-image
```

Perhaps the mount target inside the container may not be a new disk, it has to be a folder on an existing disk.